# "Object must be from the Realm being queried" crash on ChangeLogger notification

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using RealmSwift + RBQFetchedResultsController to try to get automatic tableview updates when I add new objects in a background queue, and I seem to be missing a step.

Previously, I wasn't firing any notifications, and my `FetchedResultsController` was inert after initial population. I could add objects willy-nilly in my background thread without issue.

Now, I've changed my `realm.add()` calls to the RBQ supplied `realm.addWithNotification()`, and I now get this crash after the notification fires: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value origin', reason: 'Object must be from the Realm being queried'`

It's possible that I've ran into a bug with RBQFetchResultsController, but it seems more likely that I'm doing something incorrect in my model layer. Some relevant code:

### DataStore class

```
class func threadedRealm() -> Realm {
    if NSThread.currentThread() == NSThread.mainThread() {
        return mainRealm
    }
    if let realm = self.threadedRealms[NSThread.currentThread()] {
        return realm
    }
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.threadedRealms[NSThread.currentThread()] = realm
    return realm
}

class func add(object: Object) -> Realm {
    let realm = self.threadedRealm()
    let type = object.dynamicType
    do {
        try realm.write {
            //If the object's class has a primary key, update/insert it, otherwise just insert it
            realm.addWithNotification(object, update: type.primaryKey() != nil)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return realm
}
```

### Message Model

```
//called from a background thread
static func saveMessage(json: JSON, chatThread: ChatThread) -> Message {
    let message: Message
    let results = DataStore.threadedRealm().objects(Message).filter("id = %@", json["id"])
    if results.first != nil {
        message = results.first!
    } else {
        message = Message(chatId: json["chatId"].stringValue, id: json["id"].stringValue)
        message.chatThread = chatThread
        DataStore.add(message) // crash here
    }        
    return message
}
```

Some debugging steps I've already taken:

1. I've confirmed via the Realm Browser that the Message object is being inserted successfully before the crash
2. I've stepped through the stack trace and confirmed that the crash is triggered after the notification fires, as a result of methods invoked by RBQFetchedResultsController
3. I've confirmed in the debugger that `message` and `chatThread` have the same realm, and that `threadedRealm()` is returning what I'd expect throughout the whole process.

This is where I run out of ideas. It seems like a pretty simple use case, one that mirrors pretty exactly what RBQFetchedResultsController suggests on their documentation page, but I must be missing something. If anyone has any suggestions, they'd be greatly appreciated.

Oh, and here's a stack trace, in case that helps.

```
#1 in RLMPrecondition(bool, NSString*, NSString*, ...)
#2 in (anonymous namespace)::add_link_constraint_to_query(realm::Query&, NSPredicateOperatorType, (anonymous namespace)::ColumnReference const&, RLMObject*)
#3 in void (anonymous namespace)::do_add_constraint_to_query<(anonymous namespace)::ColumnReference, objc_object* __strong>(realm::Query&, RLMPropertyType, NSPredicateOperatorType, unsigned long, (anonymous namespace)::ColumnReference, objc_object* __strong)
#4 in void (anonymous namespace)::add_constraint_to_query<(anonymous namespace)::ColumnReference, objc_object* __strong>(realm::Query&, RLMPropertyType, NSPredicateOperatorType, unsigned long, (anonymous namespace)::ColumnReference, objc_object* __strong)
#5 in (anonymous namespace)::update_query_with_value_expression(RLMSchema*, RLMObjectSchema*, realm::Query&, NSString*, objc_object*, NSComparisonPredicate*)
#6 in (anonymous namespace)::update_query_with_predicate(NSPredicate*, RLMSchema*, RLMObjectSchema*, realm::Query&)
#7 in (anonymous namespace)::update_query_with_predicate(NSPredicate*, RLMSchema*, RLMObjectSchema*, realm::Query&)
#8 in RLMUpdateQueryWithPredicate(realm::Query*, NSPredicate*, RLMSchema*, RLMObjectSchema*)
#9 in -[RLMResults objectsWithPredicate:]::$_10::operator()() const
#10 in auto translateErrors<-[RLMResults objectsWithPredicate:]::$_10>(-[RLMResults objectsWithPredicate:]::$_10&&, NSString*)
#11 in -[RLMResults objectsWithPredicate:]
#12 in -[RBQFetchRequest fetchObjects]
#13 in -[RBQFetchedResultsController createStateObjectWithFetchRequest:realm:cache:cacheRealm:]
#14 in -[RBQFetchedResultsController calculateChangesWithAddedSafeObjects:deletedSafeObjects:changedSafeObjects:realm:]
#15 in __58-[RBQFetchedResultsController registerChangeNotifications]_block_invoke
#16 in -[RBQRealmNotificationManager sendNotificationsWithRealm:entityChanges:]
#17 in __50-[RBQRealmChangeLogger registerChangeNotification]_block_invoke
#18 in -[RLMRealm sendNotifications:]
#19 in (anonymous namespace)::RLMNotificationHelper::did_change(std::__1::vector<realm::BindingContext::ObserverState, std::__1::allocator<realm::BindingContext::ObserverState> > const&, std::__1::vector<void*, std::__1::allocator<void*> > const&)
#20 in realm::_impl::transaction::commit(realm::SharedGroup&, realm::BindingContext*)
#21 in realm::Realm::commit_transaction()
#22 in -[RLMRealm commitWriteTransaction:]
#23 in -[RLMRealm transactionWithBlock:error:]
#24 in Realm.write(() -> ()) throws -> ()
#25 in static DataStore.add(Object) -> Realm
#26 in static Message.saveMessage(JSON, chatThread : ChatThread) -> Message
#27 in static Message.messagesFromAPIResponse(APIResponse) -> ()
```

Comment: Hi, I created RBQFetchedResultsController. Could you share how you created the RBQFetchRequest?

Comment: Hey @AdamFish, your comment was enough to fix our issue. The FetchRequest was based on a ChatThread object, which was owned by the main thread. I modified the fetch request to be based on the thread's primary key instead, and everything works exactly as expected.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you were able to fix it!